# How to dispose a Dialog with the back Button

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I would like my [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) Dialog to get disposed when the User presses on the hardware back button, how would I do that?

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Hi");
dialog.add(new Label("World"));
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `setBackCommand()` with an empty string Command:
It is also recommended to use the `setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds` for devices that does not have a back Button such as iOS

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Hi");
dialog.add(new Label("World"));
dialog.setBackCommand(new Command(""){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        dialog.dispose();
    }            
});
dialog.setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(true);
dialog.show();
```